# How to send and receive encrypted email using PHP

Tags: php, email, pdf-generation, public-key-encryption

I work at a hospital and have developed a way to estimate the total patient financial responsibility for services, after insurance has paid it's obligation, and before any services are rendered. A lot of patients are calling for quotes, and I wanted to find a secure way to email those results to the patient at their request.

I'm considering removing all patient information from the generated quote, so there would not be any security concerns, but would like to find a way to encrypt the email, send it, and allow the patient's email client to decrypt the email.

I'm not sure how to use security certificates, though they might be the best option for me, even though I'd have to jump through corporate hoops to be granted access to internet facing hosting for certificates, all applications other than email are hospital side only.

I'm also considering creating a PDF from the generated letter and encrypting the PDF, assigning their last four of their social, or some other private info they've shared with us during the quote generation process, as their password.

Comment: Good question. The approach @Byron suggested is the best. You can also keep check if the recipient has seen the link and have someone call them if they don't.

Comment: This sounds like a useful piece of software and a great step forward in American health care.  Nice work.

Answer (score 6):

You would be better off sending a link to an SSL encrypted site that has all the information. It would not require any additional software on the client side, and would allow you to have a bit more control and accounting of who is accessing it.

You must of course secure it with username/password of some kind, you could even just use their social security + a generated hash sent in the email. The hash prevents a user from guessing random ssn's.

Comment: I was going to suggest this approach, +1. The hash could be prefilled in the URL, however.

Comment: That is the obvious answer, if you have an internet facing web hosting service, as I wrote, I don't have the ability to host my application on the internet, all my apps are only accessible from the hospital network. I have received permission to send and receive email outside our network, though that was an undertaking gaining that access. I could imagine it might be possible for corporate to allow some certificate files to be stored somewhere online, though, it would take a lot of politicking to accomplish even that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're employed by a hospital in the USA, you had better not try to email protected health information. (Similar things are true in other countries.)  Even if you scrub the patient's name out of the message, you'll definitely have the patient's email address in the message (duh!).  You'll most likely have diagnoses, dates of birth, dates of proposed care, medical record numbers, or account numbers.  That's all protected data.  Bad. Bad.  See here for the regulations, which are rigid.

http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/summary/index.html

If you want to do this, you must use TLS (https) security, and you must go to some length both to ensure that the person logging in to your secure web site is who they claim to be, and you must log accesses.

Please, if you value your job and your savings account, check with your hospital's privacy officer before sending emails with PHI in them. The ARRA 2009 law makes individuals personally liable for breaches even if they work for corporations.  Plus, your hospital does NOT want its name in lights here.

http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/breachnotificationrule/postedbreaches.html

You could use encrypted email, as long as the unencrypted part (e.g. the subject line) only said "here's the information you requested" or something like that.  But, you know, many persons seeking medical care won't be able to cope with a complex addin to their mail client software.

The PGP company offers an encrypted email gateway system that some people with PHI use.

http://www.pgp.com/products/universal_gateway_email/index.html

But you should still check with your privacy officer.

Comment: This was just plain rude and insulting.

Comment: Roger, not intended that way. HIPPA is deadly serious business.  The new laws really do "pierce the corporate veil" and hold individuals personally accountable for breaches.  With health care information "hey I got an idea!" needs to be tempered with security-officer review.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this about 10 years ago using [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy). [GPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) is a similar library.

These options may be way too involved for an older user though, as I believe they both involve the recipient installing a certificate of sorts on their end.

Might be a good place to start looking...

Answer (score -1):

From what I know, this is essentially impossible unless the recipient is also using the same e-mail client. The problem is that even if you encrypt on your end, the recipient will received a garbage message simply because they don't have the functionality to decrypt.

While I was typing this, TomWilsonFL posted information on a possible encryption method, but you will still need to provide the recipient an application to decrypt the data.

Comment: Ok, this is close to what I was trying to get to, I've never used encryption email features, I thought there might be some kind of standard for email encryption, like ssl is for web pages, thanks.