# Sending encrypted email with CodeIgniter 2.0

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, email-attachments

I'm looking for a way to send an encrypted email using CodeIgniter 2.0 Email Library.
Any libraries out there or a way to extend the built-in library to send encrypted email?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the text body or attach encrypted attachments ?

Comment: what u mean by encrypted?  how would receivers to decrypt it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send and receive encrypted email using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241461/how-to-send-and-receive-encrypted-email-using-php)

Comment: @Jun1st PGP would be my guess

Comment: seems like something for CI 3.0: http://codeigniter.com/nightly_user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not the CI 2.0 built-in library, but you can send encrypted email with Postmark - and I believe the plugin for CI is very similar to the standard CI email library. http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-build.html